# How to remove empty option in a select box while dynamically removing the option

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJs for couple of weeks.I tried a snippet with select box.First i face empty option issue while loading I googled and solved.Now if i remove the option by dynamically the same empty option comes and i am getting this Error `"value is undefined`" This is my [issue](https://jsbin.com/xobefowita/edit?html,js,console,output).Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed empty option at init by assigning `$scope.selected` property to one of `$scope.opt1` items.

You have to to this another time after removing an item from that list.
It's because you have removed selected item and now your `$scope.selected` property doesn't match any of existing properties.

```
$scope.addOption = function(){

  if($scope.selected !== undefined){
    $scope.opt2.push($scope.selected);
    $scope.opt1 = $scope.opt1.filter(function(value) {
      return $scope.selected.name !== value.name;
    });
    $scope.selected = $scope.opt1[0];
  }

};
```

Also I have changed `$.each` to `Array.prototype.filter` to prevent error throwing.

Comment: Great work!Thanks Girafa...can you tell me why that error came for $.each..It will help my improvement!!

Comment: It's because you have a loop over an array and then change the length of that array. jQuery.each method gets the array length only once before actual looping. After you have removed an item from the array, loop goes to non-existent element which is undefined now and then tries to get `.name` of that undefined.

Comment: After adding all the items it is selecting the empty option and how to empty the scope after adding all the items because after adding all options it points the last item

Comment: I don't understand what else do you want to implement. After the first list is empty there is of course nothing to select.

Comment: I mean after adding all the items in the first select box it is focusing empty option in the first select box..how to solve that issue..thanks in advance

Comment: I think select cannot be empty, so you decide what to do :)